# Why the HashMap is unsafed in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have [seen something](http://tekmarathon.com/2012/12/04/hashmap-internal-implementation-analysis-in-java/) that explains the reason why the HashMap is unsafed in multiple thread.

It said, when do the resize, the entire sequence of objects in linked list gets reversed, and it shows the example:

> For example, lets assume there are 3 keys with same hashcode and hence stored in linked list inside a bucket [below format is in object_value(current_address, next_address) ]
>      Initial structure: 1(100, 200) --> 2(200, 300) --> 3(300, null)
>      After resizing by thread-1: 3(300, 200) --> 2(200, 100) --> 1(100, null)
>      When thread-2 starts resizing, its again starts with 1st element by placing it at the head:
>   1(100, 300) --> 3(300, 200) --> 2(200, 100) ==> which becomes a infinite loop for next insertion and thread hangs here.

I was so confused about the example,

Initial Structure: 1 -> 2 -> 3

Thread1: 3->2->1

Thread2: 1 -> 3 ->2 why?

Could anyone help me to analyse the example or show a more detail exmpale? Thanks.

Comment: Oh please. Do you have to create and post pictures when you could far more easily have posted the original text? Why waste time and space on this epic scale? And considering the answer is given in the same paragraph of your citation it's hard to see why you're posting the question at all.

Comment: I am confused on what you are asking: Are you interested to know why the internal linked list got reversed?  Or do you want to know why HashMap is not thread safe?

Comment: I tried to follow the logic of that article. I looked into the source code of HashMap to understand how that infinite loop is formed, but couldn't see it. Therefore I wouldn't mind an explanation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear on what you are asking about.

Are you interested to know why HashMap is not thread-safe? Or you are just interested on knowing the reason for the "reversing" effect during resize (which is one of the reason for the thread-unsafetiness)?

For latter question (which is the one you explicitly asked in the question), here is the reason:

By inspecting HashMap's source code, there is a `transfer()` method which is responsible to move the entries from the old table to the new one:

```
void transfer(Entry[] newTable) {
    Entry[] src = table;
    int newCapacity = newTable.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        Entry<K,V> e = src[j];
        if (e != null) {
            src[j] = null;
            do {
                Entry<K,V> next = e.next;
                int i = indexFor(e.hash, newCapacity);
                e.next = newTable[i];
                newTable[i] = e;
                e = next;
            } while (e != null);
        }
    }
}
```

The reverse is the side-effect of the above logic (look closer to the do-while loop and it shouldn't be difficult to understand).

If you are asking why they want to make the order reverse, then you better ask the author.  However I can tell you it is not the intention for them to "reverse" the order.  Due to HashMap have no gaurantee on the order of iteration, implementation do no need to maintain any order.  As long as the result is correct, implementer can choose the easiest and fastest way to implement the resize logic.  Current logic is their choice.

---

Update: If you just want to know of a case that is non-thread-safe, there are other things that is more obvious.

For example, when adding an entry to the Map, the logic is like: first calculate the index to put the entry to , add it to that index in the table, and if table is "full", then do resize.

There can be a case that, Thread one is trying to add an entry, and the original table size is 100, and then hash code is 101, then it find out the index is 1.

At this time, another thread comes in, and add an entry to the table, and found the table is "full", and then it do the resize. Size of new table is now 200.

Then at this time, thread 1 go to the step of actually putting the entry to the table and trying to put to index 1.  However, with the new table of size 200, the correct index to put should be 101 instead of 1.

The result is the map is resulted in a corrupted state.

There are even more different example of thread unsafetiness.

---

For the given example you mentioned.  Here is a specific example on how it may cause problem:

Assuming an existing hash table:

```
[0] -> E1 -> E2 -> E3 -> null
[1]
```

Resize will do something like:

```
- Create a new table
(old table)
[0] -> E1 -> E2 -> E3 -> null
[1]

(new table)
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]


- iterate thru the original entries, and put it one by one 

(Put E1 to new table)
[0] -       E2 -> E3
[1]  \
      \
       v
[0]  -> E1 ->null
[1]
[2]
[3]

(Put E2 to new table)
[0] ------      E3
[1]        \
            \
             v
[0]  -> E2 -> E1 ->null
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

You will see at this point, index 0 of old table is still pointing to E1

If another thread come in and trying to do the resize, doing resize in such intermediate state can cause all sort of problem : wrong `next` as in your original article, or missing entry in the resulting table etc.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian, I'm sorry that I didn't clear describe my problem, the example explained what would occur in multiple threads, I couldn't understand, and I am asking why HashMap is not thread safe.

Comment: If you just want to know a case that is going to be non-thread-safe, then there is something even more obvious.  Please check my update

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle Java documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an
>   instance already contains is not a structural modification.) This is
>   typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally
>   encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be
>   "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method. This is best
>   done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to
>   the map:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
```

When you add elements to a hashmap, it's internal structure is changed, so you cannot trust the ordering of elements in a hashmap. If you want to maintain ordering, use a TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer from here:

http://mailinator.blogspot.hu/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Also, thanks